# UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad for ipad

Tags: ipad, ios6, uikeyboardtype

For iPad application I want to change type of keyboard from default to UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad. But it shows me default only. And I am using iOS 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your UITextfield use this in code:

```
myTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```

In iOS 5.1 or 6.1 iPad only these keyboard are available:

- UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
- UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation
- UIKeyboardTypeURL
- UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad
- UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad
- UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress
- UIKeyboardTypeTwitter

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could provide a source for this list.